# How can I re-enable Headphones?

Tags: audio

This PC restarted whilst I was playing a game.  After the restart, there was no longer any sound coming from the headphones.  I've tried looking for solutions on the net, but haven't found anything that's worked.  Here's what I've tried:

- opening the Sound Control Panel and ensuring that the 'Show Disconnected Devices' and 'Show Disabled Devices options are selected: the Headphones are not showing up in the list of Playback Devices;
- updating and rolling back Realtek and Nvidia Audio Drivers.  After updating the Nvidia one (but before updating the Realtek one), the headphones were now the default playback device, but there was still no sound;
- did a System Restore;
- tried to follow a possible solution posted on Youtube which involved opening an app entitled 'RtkNGUI64' from the Realtek folder in Program Files and then enabling 'playback multi-streaming' (was unable to open it).

Comment: Are your headphones connected via a 3.5 mm jack?

Comment: Yes.  By the way, I have to go out soon so probably won't be around for the rest of the day.

Comment: Last time I had a similar issue, I resorted to updating the audio drivers with Snappy Driver Installer (https://sdi-tool.org/), because only it would propose to install "older but better" drivers (that's how the program calls them), and that was all it took. If you decide to go down that route, don't download the whole driver collection on first run, just the index, check the "older but better" box in the left pane, and let SDI scan your PC for drivers that require updating. Install the sound drivers it proposes and restart (no Fast Startup) with your headphones plugged in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the headphone playback device back?](https://superuser.com/questions/490136/how-can-i-get-the-headphone-playback-device-back)

Comment: @Ramhound not directly, but it promoted me to take a look at the Realtek Audio Manager and in so doing (this is both embarrassing and fairly hilarious) I realised I had the headphones plugged into the mic socket.  I had it in my head that pink was the headphones for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to plug them into the Headphones socket, not the Mic socket ha; well either that or they work when plugged into the Mic Socket but not the Headphones one (can't actually check right now as the light is dim in this room), but guessing it's the 1st option (it's the green one they're in anyway as opposed to the pink one).